# Android XML bitmap gives error "Invalid Start tag bitmap" error

Tags: android

I want to use a xml bitmap file that points to a bitmap file

I am getting an error "Invalid start tag bitmap". The file is placed in res/drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:src="@drawable/back"
 android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Kindly help

Comment: Are you sure that problem in this xml exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While dragging the mouse, the file got moved by mistake to some other folder. That caused all the issues. Thanks a lot everyone though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it with `item`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <bitmap 
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when creating .xml file, you have used "Android XML Value File".
use "Android XML File" instead and in next page select bitmap.